# WPF centered bar issue

Tags: wpf

I have recently started learning C# WPF UI and a bar (see below image) appears anytime I run my application. I may have done some reckless changes that may have caused the problem. Some advice?
[image]

**Code:**

```
<Window x:Class="WPFHello.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFHello"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="Hello" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Label Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="1.575,1.359" FontSize="20" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: What operating system, what version of C, and what are you trying to do? Any chance you can paste your code here?

Comment: "I may have done some reckless changes that may have caused the problem."  What are we supposed to do with this information?

Comment: I am using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017, Version 15.8.7 with Microsoft.NET Framework Version 4.7.03056. I will add the code of my XAML right now. @MarkDeven

Comment: I found the problem with this issue on another *[post][1]*. [1]:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36618494/disable-visual-studio-2015-extra-debug-option

Answer (score 0):

This is a debugging tool which appears every time when you run your application.

You can disable it like this:
Go to Tools –> Options –> Debugging –> General –> Un-check Enable UI Debugging Tools for XAML.

Hope This will help you.
Thank you.